# How to read a txt file of byte literals into UTF-8 strings?

Tags: python, utf-8

I have a .txt file with lines like these:

```
b'Afrikaans'
b'\xe1\x8a\xa0\xe1\x88\x9b\xe1\x88\xad\xe1\x8a\x9b'
b'\xd0\x90\xd2\xa7\xd1\x81\xd1\x88\xd3\x99\xd0\xb0'
```

How can I turn these lines into UTF-8 strings so that the output is like these:

```
Afrikaans
አማርኛ
Аҧсшәа
```

I tried this but only got strings with the same values as the byte literals:

```
    with open("encoded.txt", "rb") as filename:
        line = filename.readline().strip()
        while line:
            print(line.decode("utf-8"))
            line = filename.readline().strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

The lines are Python literals, so `ast.literal_eval` can parse them to Python byte strings:

```
import ast

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(ast.literal_eval(line).decode('utf8'))
```

Output:

```
Afrikaans
አማርኛ
Аҧсшәа
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem quite easily. Is there another way to solving it without importing a module?

Comment: @muon012 It's a built-in module.  It comes with Python.

Comment: @muon012 You could do `print(line.strip()[2:-1].encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))` but...yuck.  Better to figure out why byte literals were written to the file in the first place and fix that.